# System.Windows.Threading not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to use `using System.Windows.Threading;` but it gives me

> The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows`.

I have the latest version of .NET.

Comment: Do you have a local variable as `threading`?

Comment: Why do you want to use that namespace? Is it a WPF application? The types of that namespace reside in `WindowBase.dll`, which should be a reference for WPF applications anyway. Depending on the type of application perhaps use a different namespace or add a reference to that assembly.

Comment: No I have created a new `C#` class         and in the very first line it is giving the error.I want to use it for `DispatcherTimer`

Answer (score 16):

It's in **WindowsBase.dll**, after add the reference, it works!

(if you don't know how to add reference, see [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx).)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you've added a reference to WindowsBase.dll to your project and then you should be good to go. have a look at - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you're still having trouble please attach your .csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a reference to the assembly containing the class you want to use.

Additionally, you probably don't want to use WPF classes (from System.Windows.Threading) if you did not create the project with the WPF application wizard.

**Edit:** In Windows Forms applications, the obvious choice for a timer is [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and in some cases [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

It's `using System.Threading;` not `using System.Windows.Threading`. Don't know if you used that in your code and just made a mistake on the question, but there it is.